# casting and polymorphism

Tags: c++

Please see the following simple code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    virtual bool cmp(const A& a) const {cout << "cmp A" << endl; return true;}
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
    bool cmp(const B& b) const {cout << "cmp B" << endl; return false;;}
};


int main()
{

    A a1;
    A a2;
    B b1;
    B b2;

    a1.cmp(a2); // as expected
    b1.cmp(b2); // as expected

    a1.cmp(b1); // upcasting
    // b2.cmp(a2); // conversion needed


    // Here is the problematic part:
    A* pa;
    pa = new B;

    pa -> cmp (b1); // Why why why the cmp of A runs?

    return 0;
}
```

I just can't understand it - there is vptr and vtbl and a function that matches exactly to the call, without any casting. So why is cmp of class A is called?

Any logical answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not overriding the operator. You have 2 **different** operators in your classes.

To override a method or operator, the signature has to match perfectly. That means:

- name
- parameters
- cv-qualifiers

The base class operator takes a `const A&` as parameter, the derived class takes a `const B&`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `A::cmp` and `B::cmp` signatures does not match.

And `b1` is first converted to `const A &` and `A::cmp` is called

Answer (score 1):

You have two overrides

```
A::cmp(const A&)
B::cmp(const B&)
```

So when you do `pa->cmp()` It calls `A::cmp` because type of pa is A at compile time. and there is no point of vptr here because you are not overriding anything at all.

It will be overriding If you have

```
bool B::cmp(const A& b)
```

which overrides the signature `A::cmp(const A& b)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's expected, because `bool cmp(const B& b) const` doesn't override a virtual method of the base class, since they have different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Because `B::cmp()` signature is different from `A::cmp()`. So `B::cmp()` is NOT overriding `A::cmp()`, but hiding it, it's not virtual and doesn't known by call through `A*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method on B is 'hiding' the base class method, so you can't see it through B.  See the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while co-variant return types are allowed in the overriding virtual function, co-variant argument types are not! So you hide the base virtual function, instead of overriding it.